# Create Class Implicitly In Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that its job is generate a python class implicitly according to the given name that pass throw the function. After that I want to create field and method implicitly for the generated class too. I don't know how can start it. Can someone help...

Comment: WHat are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Does it *need* to be of a specific name? You could just generate it then assign it to whatever variable like `NewClassName = OldClassName` or `ClassName = ClassFactory(**options)`. The only "downside" is that `repr`ing it will give the original name.

Comment: You can create classes dynamically based on input parameters, is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: If you just want to create class in function, `type()` will be your friend. If you want others, please declare more details.

Comment: Why do you need a class created at runtime. That's *very* unusual that you have a real usecase for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. But I think @root give the true answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you really need a class? For "types" created at runtime, maybe namedtuple would be a solution.

```
from collections import namedtuple
MyType= namedtuple("MyType", "field1 method1")
x = MyType(field1="3", method1=lambda x: x+1)
print x.field1, x.method1(3)
```

Comment: `MyType` not define after create this by namedtuple. Any idea?

Comment: mmm, my code works on my box. Do you use exactly my code? If not, please show me your code so I can look for errors.

Comment: For me, the output is `3 4`, also on Python 2.7. Could anybody else please verify it works? So we could concentrate on why it fails on your system.

Comment: Thank you @Thorsten Kranz. But I do my work with the other snippet.

Comment: I got the same error, try changing `MyTuple` to `MyType`; that fixes it.

Comment: Damn... I copied the sample to SO, then fixed this problem in my editor and forgot to fix it here also. Edited my sample now.

Comment: Yes. That's true. I change `MyTuple` to `MyType` and it work good.

Comment: @VahidJavaherifar: `nametuple` instances are immutable -- try adding a `x.field1 = 42` at the end of the code in the answer. This may or may not be OK for your intended usage.

Comment: It's OK. I want immutable class.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this using `type()`:

```
def my_func(self):
    return 'my_func to become my_method!'

def class_maker(name,**kwargs):
    return type(name, (object,), kwargs)

A = class_maker('MyClass',my_method=my_func, field='this is my_field!')
inst = A()

print inst.my_method()
print inst.field
print inst
print A
```

Outputs:

```
my_func to become my_method!
this is my_field!
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x962902c>
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```